# In GAMS, how do I write a function of the variables?

Tags: gams-math

When coding in GAMS and defining my EQUATIONS, I sometimes need to reuse a certain function of the variables. How do I define this function so that I can reuse it, as opposed to having to constantly write it out in my equation definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro to do this. The syntax is documented here: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_DollarControlOptions.html#UG_DollarControl_MacrosInGAMS

You could for example define a function 'sqrtsqr'

```
$macro sqrtsqr(x) sqrt(x*x)
```

And use it in your equations

```
my_equation.. sqrtsqr(x) =E= y;
```